# Youtube viewport bigger than real display size

Tags: video, display, resolution, youtube, viewport

When checking "Stats for nerds" on Youtube:

[image]

When in fullscreen it shows the viewport as 2400x1350 while my monitor is 1920x1080. How can the viewport be bigger than the monitor resolution?

I'm using Firefox and KDE Plasma on Fedora.

Comment: This likely means that YouTube is scaling down the video.

Comment: Or they have used a different font size.

Comment: Are you watching a 1440p video?